# unable send email in zend framework

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2

I try create contact form, but when i send email i see: Unable send email. Below is my code for sending email. What is wrong with it?

```
public function indexAction(){
    $emailForm = new ContactForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $emailForm->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($emailForm->isValid()) {
            $mail = new Mail\Message();
            $mail->addFrom('address@example.com');
            $mail->setSubject('email from web');
            $mail->addTo('address@example.com');
            $mail->setBody('<h3> Message: </h3> ' . $request->getPost('message'));

            $transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
            $transport->send($mail);
        }
    }
    return array(
        'form' => $emailForm
    );
}
```

Comment: Message: Unable to send mail: Unknown error

Comment: Sendmail send an email through your mail server. Do you have mail server?

Comment: I already solved this, I find out that i have the wrong password for email(sender) in my sendmail.ini :)

Comment: @user5503823 Then please delete your question so others are not wasting time on reading it...